# What this array init syntax mean? (elements with keys)

Tags: go

I recently found the code below:

```
var noEscape = [256]bool{
    'A': true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
    'a': true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
    '0': true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
    '-': true,
    '.': true,
    '_': true,
    '~': true,
}
```

I understand that this `[N]bool` is initialized with N `false` (zeros) by default. And if the index followed by a colon is specified values can are defined form the index (inclusive). Where is it described? What types can be used as an index value (there is a `char` in the example)?

Comment: Go doesn't have a `char` type. Those are `rune` literals and `rune` is a type alias for `int32`. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an array or slice literal, the index values must be constants. From the docs on ["composite literals"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

> For array and slice literals the following rules apply:
>
> - Each element has an associated integer index marking its position in the array.
> - An element with a key uses the key as its index; the key must be a constant integer expression.
> - An element without a key uses the previous element's index plus one. If the first element has no key, its index is zero.

The literal characters in the example are untyped [constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants), which just happen to be written as a single rune literal. If you were to assign any of those values to a variable to use as the index, the code would not compile.

Comment: reflect.TypeOf('a') returns int32 even via a variable. http://play.golang.org/p/udDxnPquaA

Comment: @voutasaurus: The "default type" of an untyped constant written as a rune literal is `rune`, which is simply an alias for `int32`. Since reflect has to convert it to a valid type to determine what it is, both versions print `int32`. I added a link to the "Constants" spec which explains default types.